# How to add a colorbar for a hist2d plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Well, I know how to add a colour bar to a figure, when I have created the figure directly with `matplotlib.pyplot.plt`.

```
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# normal distribution center at x=0 and y=5
x = np.random.randn(100000)
y = np.random.randn(100000) + 5

# This works
plt.figure()
plt.hist2d(x, y, bins=40, norm=LogNorm())
plt.colorbar()
```

But why does the following not work, and what would I need to add to the call of `colorbar(..)` to make it work.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist2d(x, y, bins=40, norm=LogNorm())
fig.colorbar()
# TypeError: colorbar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mappable'

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist2d(x, y, bins=40, norm=LogNorm())
fig.colorbar(ax)
# AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'autoscale_None'

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
h = ax.hist2d(x, y, bins=40, norm=LogNorm())
plt.colorbar(h, ax=ax)
# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'autoscale_None'
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You are almost there with the 3rd option. You have to pass a `mappable` object to `colorbar` so it knows what colormap and limits to give the colorbar. That can be an `AxesImage` or `QuadMesh`, etc.

In the case of [`hist2D`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d), the tuple returned in your `h` contains that `mappable`, but also some other things too.

From the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d):

> **Returns:**
> The return value is (counts, xedges, yedges, Image).

So, to make the colorbar, we just need the `Image`.

To fix your code:

```
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# normal distribution center at x=0 and y=5
x = np.random.randn(100000)
y = np.random.randn(100000) + 5

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
h = ax.hist2d(x, y, bins=40, norm=LogNorm())
fig.colorbar(h[3], ax=ax)
```

Alternatively:

```
counts, xedges, yedges, im = ax.hist2d(x, y, bins=40, norm=LogNorm())
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
```

Comment: `fig.colorbar(im)` also works, and seems more consistent with the rest of the answer.

Comment: @ThomasH , your suggestion also gives more coherent output in a Jupyter noteboook