# Showing subplot colorbar for a matplotlib streamplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

What I want to do is simple: for a plot created using `plt.subplots()` I would like to display a color bar.

So, this is what I do:

```
def plotVF(self, u, v):
    m = np.sqrt(np.power(u, 2) + np.power(v, 2))

    xrange = np.linspace(0, u.shape[1], u.shape[1]);
    yrange = np.linspace(0, u.shape[0], u.shape[0]);

    x, y = np.meshgrid(xrange, yrange)
    mag = np.hypot(u, v)
    scale = 1
    lw = scale * mag / mag.max()

    f, ax = plt.subplots()
    h = ax.streamplot(x, y, u, v, color=mag, linewidth=lw, density=3, arrowsize=1, norm=plt.Normalize(0, 70))
    ax.set_xlim(0, u.shape[1])
    ax.set_ylim(0, u.shape[0])
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    cbar = f.colorbar(h, ax=ax)
    cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=5) 

    plt.show()
```

Accordingly to what is shown in the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/pcolormesh_levels.html).
However, I keep receiving:

```
AttributeError: 'StreamplotSet' object has no attribute 'autoscale_None'
```

This example has only one plot, but I'll have more than one, that's why I'm not directly using `plt.colorbar().`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a colorbar to a figure in matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42387471/how-to-add-a-colorbar-to-a-figure-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ax.streamplot` returns a `StreamplotSet` object. This is not a mappabple instance that can be used in the making of a `colorbar`. However, as per the [docs for `streamplot`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot), it contains the `LineCollection` and a collection of `FancyArrowPatch` objects. We can use the `LineCollection` to make the colorbar.

It can be accessed from you `h`, using `h.lines`. Thus, to make your colorbar, you need:

```
cbar = f.colorbar(h.lines, ax=ax)
```

You can see an example of this in the `matplotlib` gallery, [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/streamplot_demo_features.html).